# Two switch case values in angular

Tags: angular

In php and java we can do

```
case 1:
case 2:
   echo "something";
```

so that when the value is  1 or 2 "something" will be printed on the screen, i am building an angular application i am doing something like the below

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="data.type">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'multi-choice'">FORM 1</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'singe-choice'">FORM 1</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'range'">FORM 2</div>
</div>
```

The form which is used for single choice can be used for mutiple choice , but i tried something like below to make it more organisable

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="data.type">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'multi-choice' || 'singe-choice'">FORM 1</div>
</div>
```

My bad luck it didnt work, can anyone suggest the better way to do this.

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12174

Answer (score 215, accepted):

(Un)fortunately you can‘t; the `ngSwitch` is quite “dumb” if you look at the source code: it‘s just a `===` between the case value and the switch value. You have two options, but both of them are far from great.

Option 1 is using the directive `*ngSwitchDefault`, but this will only work if all your multiple cases are FORM 1:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="data.type">
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>FORM 1</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'range'">FORM 2</div>
</div>
```

The other option, which is quite verbose, is doing something like this:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="data.type">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="data.type === 'multi-choice' || data.type === 'singe-choice' ? data.type : '' ">FORM 1</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'range'">FORM 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am going for the second because the default is meaning something else, thank you for this idea!

Comment: I'm throwing this out there, if someone needs to `or` a `Switch Case` ... maybe you need a `*ngIf` instead of a switch :\

Comment: for some unknown reason, this is not working in angular v6. however the 3rd answer is working. (by MoshMage)

Comment: Can be improved: `*ngSwitchCase="['multi-choice', 'singe-choice'].includes(data.type) ? data.type : '' "`

Comment: I fixed the problem using **second option**. I do not understand why the first does not work. Can you have a look at [Using extra parameter in ngSwitchCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543744/using-extra-parameter-in-ngswitchcase/57543774?noredirect=1#comment101551239_57543774) please? Regards...

Comment: I used the following syntax `*ngSwitchCase="{ 'multi-choice': 1, 'singe-choice': 1 }[data.type] ? data.type : ''"`

Comment: A default inside a switch is rarely a good idea. It will usually create future hidden bugs (when new values are added).

Answer (score 104):

You can use `ngTemplateOutlet` to implement this:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="variable">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="1">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="form1"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="2">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="form1"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="3">FORM 2</ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>FORM 3</ng-container>
    <ng-template #form1>FORM 1</ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

---

#### Update

While Angular still [considering](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14659) such feature, there is jonrimmer's [switch-cases.directive.ts](https://gist.github.com/jonrimmer/eaabd619e2edeaebed83b7bc68f33daf). Usage example:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="variable">
    <ng-container *jrSwitchCases="[1, 2]">FORM 1</ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="3">FORM 2</ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>FORM 3</ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest and least hacky solution. It is also hinted to in [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase): "Each switch-case statement contains an in-line HTML template or template reference"

Comment: One word of warning: the content of `#form1` will re-render between switchCase 1 and 2. For many this won't matter, but if the component is complex, then for now you're better off with an *ngIf.

Comment: What will happen when someone adds a type=5 ? A default is a very bad idea here. Why is the value 4 more important than the values 1 and 2? I have seen endless bugs resulting from this pattern by too many developers.

Comment: Just FYI, you can reduce that template by nearly 2 times as you can provide the template as an input too: `<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="1" [ngTemplateOutlet]="form1">` which will let you avoid the nested `ng-container`

Answer (score 81):

You can also use the following, which is a lot more flexible. You can then put anything that evaluates to boolean as the *ngSwitchCase value.

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="true">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="data.type === 'multi-choice' || data.type === 'singe-choice'">FORM 1</div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="data.type === 'range'">FORM 2</div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>FORM 3</div>
</div>
```

The advantage this has over using *ngIf blocks is that you can still specify a default.

Comment: This one that worked for me, but it is strange to switch a 'true' statement.

Comment: @GuilhermeSampaio strange !== bad. Such approach can be very useful sometimes.

Comment: @Tomek yes! It was useful for me! :D

Comment: The problem is you have a default (another name for a try/catch/continue)

Comment: The new `@if ` syntax can easily let you have an `else` case to cover the default, I'd really argue to prefer now the new syntax over a "hacked" ngSwitch https://angular.dev/api/core/@if

Answer (score 30):

Here's a variation that combines Fabio's second answer with brian3kb's to produce a more condensed solution without obfuscating meaning.

If there are multiple matches for a case it uses `array.includes()` instead of comparing each option individually.

It is especially useful if there are more than two matches as it will be much more condensed relative to the accepted answer.

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="data.type">
   <div *ngSwitchCase="['multi-choice', 'singe-choice'].includes(data.type) ? data.type : ''">FORM 1</div>
   <div *ngSwitchCase="'range'">FORM 2</div>
   <div *ngSwitchDefault>FORM 3</div>
</div>
```

If the matches happen to be in a variable, you can use `array.indexOf()` to avoid the use of the conditional ternary operator.

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="data.type">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="matches[matches.indexOf(data.type)]">FORM 1</div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

Like [MoshMage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587811/moshmage) suggested, I ended up using an `*ngIf` to handle this for the components that handled several of the options:

```
 *ngIf="['Transformation', 'Field Mapping', 'Filter'].includes(selectedWorkflow.type)"
```

Comment: While this reads nicely, be aware that you it'd be a good idea to have the change detection strategy set to OnPush for this component and to make sure that it's not a component that is going to be refresh very often. During each change detection cycle, you will create a new array and 3 new strings and go through the array to check if the value is in here. I know we shouldn't do too much micro optimisations either, but just make sure this component isn't refreshed too often

Answer (score 12):

It could be achieved using the `ngTemplateOutlet` directive:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="colour">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'green'">:)</ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'yellow'">;)</ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'black'" [ngTemplateOutlet]="sad"></ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'darkgrey'" [ngTemplateOutlet]="sad"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #sad>:(</ng-template>
```

Comment: Why sad, not glad?

Answer (score 5):

use `ngFor`:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="column">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let numeric of ['case1', 'case2']">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="numeric">
      {{ element[column] | currency }}
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is (included in)/(very similar to) [this answer](link/to/answer), and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it:

In your `.component.ts`:

```
getFormType(type: string) {
  switch(type) {
    case 'singe-choice':
    case 'multi-choice':
      return 'singe-choice|multi-choice'
    default:
      return type;
  }
}
```

Then, in your template file, you can do something like this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="getFormType(data.type)">
   <div *ngSwitchCase="'singe-choice|multi-choice'">FORM 1</div>
   <div *ngSwitchCase="'range'">FORM 2</div>
   <div *ngSwitchDefault>FORM 3</div>
</div>
```

Watch out for typos though...

Answer (score 2):

[The Fabio Antunes's second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40177408/11347983), but with a pipe:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'multiSwitchCase',
})
export class MultiSwitchCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T = any>(cases: T[], value: T): T {
    return cases.includes(value) ? value : cases[0];
  }
}
```

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="data.type">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="['multi-choice', 'singe-choice'] | multiSwitchCase: data.type">
    FORM 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Greetings from the year 2024!  Angular 17 now has new control flow statements that include `@switch` so answers with the `*ngSwitch` directive will be less and less relevant as time goes on.

Unfortunately, this is still an issue despite the new syntax and it being 8 years after this question was originally asked.  The new syntax doesn't support multiple cases, but this is easily overcome by switching on *true* and having an regular conditional statement.  This is very similar to [the solution originally proposed by @escapism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45950368/2497335).

```
@switch (true) { 
  @case (data.type === 'single-choice' || data.type === 'multi-choice') {
    <div>FORM 1</div>
  } 
  @default {
    <div>FORM 2</div>
  }
}
```

And here's a variation based on [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49387754/2497335).  The above solution is better unless you really want to be explicit on the expression being "switched" on.

```
@switch (data.type) { 
  @case (['multi-choice', 'single-choice'].includes(data.type) && data.type) {
    <div>FORM 1</div>
  } 
  @default {
    <div>FORM 2</div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try `ng-switch-when-separator="|"` in `ng-switch`

```
<div ng-switch="temp">
    <div ng-switch-when="1|2" ng-switch-when-separator="|"> echo "something"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that this directive is a feature of AngularJS `(aka v1)`, not Angular `(aka v2 or higher)`. Even though it's been requested in the past, it isn't yet provided on any version from Angular 2 till Angular 9 (at the date of this comment).