# Using extra parameter in ngSwitchCase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

First of all, want to emphasize that I had already have a look at many pages e.g. [Two switch case values in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176061/two-switch-case-values-in-angular) but they cannot fix my problem.

I have the following approach in the `html` page of my `Angular` project and I switch according to `i` parameter without any problem. On the other hand, there is a parameter called `loading` on component side and I also need to use this value in `ngSwitchCase`. But the following code does not work and ignore `loading` parameter's value. So, how can I use it?

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="i">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="i === 0 && loading === true">
        <!-- other stuff -->
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another `ng-container` inside with the `loading` condition.

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="i">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="0">
        <ng-container *ngIf="loading">
            // do stuff
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I already tried similar approach via `<ng-container *ngIf="loading" *ngSwitchCase="0">` and that gives the same result like that : When i=0 and loading!=true, this record is not displayed. For this case, the first record is always missing :( Any idea to fix it? On the other hand, t is really very strange that multiple parameters cannot be used in ngSwitch.

Comment: @hexadecimal can you please create a stackblitz with the problem?

Comment: Finally I fixed the problem using `<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="loading && i === 0 ? 0 : null">`. Thanks a lot for your help, voted up ;)