# Using Angular's @switch() that shares a template for several @case?

Tags: angular, switch-statement

Seven years ago, this question has been asked already [for Angular's old `ngSwitch`/ `*ngSwitchCase` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176061/two-switch-case-values-in-angular). Updating our templates to the nice new syntax, I step across the same question again: What is the best way to avoid duplicated parts in situations where several cases share the same UI?

The [Angular docs state that `@switch` does not support fallthrough](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow#switch-block---selection) (which I regard as a good choice to avoid all errors with missing breaks). But as far as I see, they didn't add something to give a list of options to a single `@case`?

So the only way is to use `<ng-template>`? E.g.

```html
  @switch (type) {
    @case ('type1') { ... }
    <ng-template #shared>Some UI shared for several cases</ng-template>
    @case ('type2') { <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="shared"/> }
    @case ('type3') { <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="shared"/> }
    @case ('type4') { ... }
```

Or, use `@default` and `@if` inside? Not sure which way would be better to understand and maintain.

Comment: IMHO this is a problem with `switch (type)` where you switch on groups, Maybe you need to switch on another variable that distinguishes the cases.

Comment: That's actually the cleanest solution to first map my type to a computed and aggregated type and use this inside the switch, thanks!! @grenobnik, Do you want to propose this as an answer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might lead to cleaner code using the `switch` statement for actual distinguished cases, and therefore it is better to map the switch variable accordingly in `ts` file (e.g. using some computed signal).

Answer (score 2):

We can use the classic `switch(true)` followed by conditionals with multiple checks, to support checking for two scenarios in one `case` block, I hope that is what you are looking for.

If we set switch to true, it will let us not do a strict string check, so for each case we can chain conditions like `@case (type === 'type2' || type === 'type3') { <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="shared"/> }` and enable code reusability. Please find below working example!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    @switch (true) {
    @case (type === 'type1') { <h1>Hi Type 1</h1> }
    @case (type === 'type2' || type === 'type3') { <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="shared"/> }
    @case (type === 'type4') { <h1>Hi Type 4</h1> }
    }

    <ng-template #shared><h1>Some UI shared for several cases (Type 2 or Type3)</h1></ng-template>
  <hr/>
  <br/>
    <button (click)="type = 'type1'">set type1</button>
    <button (click)="type = 'type2'">set type2</button>
    <button (click)="type = 'type3'">set type3</button>
    <button (click)="type = 'type4'">set type4</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  type = 'type2';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uwkvuf?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: nice workaround and maybe a bit clearer than a sequence of @else if ... thanks!

Comment: @PeterT. Do give green tick if your issue is resolved

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator in your `@case`, it is far from great and it is verbose but you can have many conditions in a simple `@case`.

Example:

```
@switch (type) {
        @case ('type1') { <div>Hi from type1</div> }
        @case (type === 'type2' || type === 'type3' ? type : '') { <ng-template #shared>Some UI shared for several cases</ng-template> }
        @case ('type4') { <div>Hi from type4</div> }
```

Comment: also an interesting option. I agree with 'far from great' ... would be cool if Angular would add some support for this case.